# Convert string of length 8 to *EUR date for comparing

Tags: datetime, ibm-midrange, datetime-format, rpgle

I want to convert a string of length 8 to a date type for comparing it. The string is formatted as DDMMYYYY (*EUR).

It has no periods for seperating the days from months and months from years. If I input a value like '01012018' to the %date BIF the compiler tells me that the expression is too short for the format *EUR:

```
 D dateEUR         s               d   datfmt(*EUR)
 C                   eval      dateEUR = %date('01012018':*EUR)
```

My previous way to compare to two dates was to take both of them, store them in datastructues, reorder the date with subfields and take the resulting, reordered date from a overlaying subfield.

Has anyone a idea of how to convert the 8A string to a DATE type in RPGLE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format you specify will depend on whether or not you store the date separators. If your date is in a 10-byte character field as DD-MM-YYYY (with the dashes), this is again EUR format:

```
      %date(alpha_date : *eur)
```

If you don'tt need standard separators with your date (DDMMYYYY in an 8-byte character field) simply append the number zero (0) to the end of the format name:

```
      %date(alpha_date : *eur0)
```

Comment: is this possible too for numeric (zoned) fields?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but if you don't need separator must do 2 steps, an example: `%char( %date(num_date : *iso) : *eur0)`

Comment: If you want to convert a numeric field with DDMMYYY to a date, use %date(num_date:*eur).

Comment: Nifriz's suggestion converts a YYYYMMDD numeric field to a date, and then converts the date to a character field in DDMMYYYY format, which is probably not what is wanted here.

Comment: Yes, it was to invert %date( %char(num_date : *iso) : *eur0)... SORRY. @Barbara_Morris numeric field support *EUR and *ISO but doesn't support *EUR0 and *ISO0.